# Set the selected Cell without pushing to new viewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I've created below code in order to change the textColor when selecting and deselecting a cell. However the issue is when the view is loaded all of the titleLabels is grey and i want the first cell to be selected. However i can't seem find out how to? i've tried just to set the first cell to another color however when i then select another cell it is not changing to grey. How can i achieve this?

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

     var cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! MenuViewCell

        cell.titleLabel?.textColor = UIColor(rgba: "#E91E63")

}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        var cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! MenuViewCell
        cell.titleLabel?.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create another function and write the changes you want to do in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method. For ex.

```
func applySelectionChangesToCell(cell:UITableViewCell) {
     cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
}
```

Now you can call this function from `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method and in `viewDidAppear`/after table reloads.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
     var cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
     applySelectionChangesToCell(cell!)
}
```

and

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
     super.viewDidAppear(animated)
     let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)
     let cell = self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)

     if let cell = cell {
          self.tableView.selectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.None)
          applySelectionChangesToCell(cell)
     }
}
```

Comment: With this approach you will end up having first row selected every time you enter this view.

Answer (score 0):

to select the first cell you, assuming that exist at least a cell

```
 override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)
    self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)?.setSelected(true, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: Nothing happens? the titleLabel is not changing to `UIColor(rgba: "#E91E63")`

Comment: create your own cell and override the setSelected function, `override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }`